# How to pass empty string as a parameter to MVC ActionMethod from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an ActionMethod

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("ControllerName/IsUniqueNotificationName/{notificationName}")]
        public IActionResult IsUniqueNotificationName(string notificationName)
        {
            var name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationName);
            var isUnique = 
              this.bannerNotificationService.IsUniqueNotificationName(notificationName);
            return this.Json(isUnique);
        }
```

my javascript method

```
        checkUniqueNotificationname = function (emailElement) {
        var notificationName = $(emailElement).val();
        let uri = "BannerNotification/IsUniqueNotificationName/" + notificationName;
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: common.buildUrlWithBasePath(uri),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    $("#BannerNotificationName").css({ "border-color": "black" });
                    $("#altFromMessageGroupValue").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#BannerNotificationName").css({ "border-color": "red" });
                    $("#altFromMessageGroupValue").show();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                common.hideLoader();
            }
        });
    };
```

when I get **notificationName** value then its hitting my ActionMethod but when I get notificationName as empty strings**(i.e; notificationName='')** its not hitting my endpoint. Instead, its hitting another endpoint which looks like

```
        [Route("ControllerName/{banName}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Details(string banName)
        {
        }
```

Could someone help me with this issuw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action to this:

```
          [HttpGet]  
        [Route("ControllerName/IsUniqueNotificationName/{notificationName?}")]
        public IActionResult IsUniqueNotificationName(string notificationName)
        {
            var empty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationName);
if (! empty){
}
            var isUnique = 
              this.bannerNotificationService.IsUniqueNotificationName(notificationName);
            return  Json(isUnique);
        }
else return BadRequest();
}
```

and   your javascript maybe need some changes too:

```
checkUniqueNotificationname = function (emailElement) {
        var notificationName = $(emailElement).val();
       if(notificationName =="")
{
   $("#BannerNotificationName").css({ "border-color": "red" });
     $("#altFromMessageGroupValue").show();
return false;
}
.....your code
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add another Method in Server

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("ControllerName/IsUniqueNotificationName")]
    public IActionResult IsUniqueNotificationName()
    {
        var name = "";
        var isUnique = 
          this.bannerNotificationService.IsUniqueNotificationName(name);
        return this.Json(isUnique);
    }
```